# Isosceles triangle generated by Intersecting circles and a point on one of them

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I am working on geometry exercises and struggling with a subproblem:

> From a point $O$ on circle $C_1$, draw a smaller circle $C_2$, so they intersect at $X$ and $Y$.
> Choose a point $R$ from $C_2$, extend $XR$ to meet $C_1$ again at $S$. Prove that $\triangle RSY$ is isosceles.

Here is my progress: In triangles $OSY$ and $OSR$, $\angle OSY = \angle OSR$ (angles subtended by equal radii of $OY$ and $OX$ of $C_2$),
$OS$ is the common side, and $OY = OR$ being radii of $C_2$.

I wished to show that $\triangle OSY \cong \triangle OSR$ but here I got the side-side-angle condition which is not working. Please follow the scale on the diagram if in doubt.

[image]

Comment: Recall that the ASS triangle could lead to 2 possibilities, namely congruent to $OSR$ or $OSX$. How can we eliminate one of them? In particular, when would$ \angle SOX = \angle SOY$?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace your former title, which IMHO is unattractive "Elementary Geometry - Kite shape in circle being symmetric" into "Isosceles triangle generated by Intersecting circles and a point on one of them". It will attract more people in the present and will likely be "hit" by queries in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend $SO$ such that it intersects $C_2$ at $M.$

[image]

Now, considering $C_2$, we get $\angle RXY= \angle RMY =\frac{\angle ROY}{2} =\frac{\angle SOY +\angle ROS}{2}.$

On the other hand, considering $C_1$, we have $\angle RXY= \angle SOY$.

Thus, we conclude that $\angle ROS= \angle SOY$. So, $\triangle SOY \cong \triangle ROS.$

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

Direct angle chasing works:

$$\angle SRY = 180^\circ - \angle YRX = \frac{1}{2} \angle XOY = \frac{1}{2}  (180^\circ - \angle YSX).$$

Thus, the angle bisector at $S$ is perpendicular to $RY$, so $SRY$ is an isosceles triangles.